# DPDK SRIOV multiple vlan traffic over single VF of SRIOV passthrough

Tags: kvm, rhel7, dpdk

When trying to use `RTE API`'s for `VLAN` offload and VLAN filtering I observe that both VLAN tagged and untagged packets are being sent out.

**API's used:**

```
rte_eth_dev_set_vlan_offload ,
rte_eth_dev_vlan_filter

DPDK - 18.08
RHEL - 7.6
Driver - igb_uio
```

Is there a way to allow only VLAN tagged packets to be sent out?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly - you're trying to strip vlan tags from tx packets? Why would you want to offload that? If you forward packets from somewhere else they already have their tags stripped by rx offload. If you create them yourself, well - you're in control.

Regardless, if you'd want to offload tx vlan **insertion**:

`rte_eth_dev_set_vlan_offload`  only sets RX offload flags.

You'll probably have to set the tx offload flag in your port config manually, like in this abridged snippet from the DPDK Flow Filtering example code:

```
struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {
    .txmode = {
        .offloads =
            DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_VLAN_INSERT,
    },
};
```

Comment: I want to do only rx offload using rte_eth_dev_set_vlan_offload and not tx vlan insertion.Based on my analysis of the VM1 and VM2 pcaps
the reception side has duplicate packets with untagged and vlan tagged packets.The sender side is sending single untagged packet in the pcap.
So I suppose the problem seems to be either in sender side DPDK or VF
or receiver side VF or DPDK.Or is it an issue with the tcpdump capture as I have taken tcpdump capture using "-i any" option and not on specific vlan interface ?